# PL/SQL frm-40735 ora-305500 error message

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

using oracle forms and sql developer.
trying to transfer the amounts in my tables to excel. In doing so, I need to divide a month into four weeks.
I tried to check each week in an if elsif loop. To find the weekly amount, I want to sum up the amounts in the date range I specified. The code is able to get inside the loop and read the records, but not the amount. Where am I doing wrong?

```sql
DECLARE 
  CURSOR c IS 
  SELECT varis_tar, tutar 
    FROM muhasebe.doviz_takip
   WHERE TRUNC(varis_tar) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                              AND TO_DATE('31/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  GROUP BY varis_tar,tutar;

  tutar1 NUMBER(9):=0; 
  tutar2 NUMBER(9):=0; 
  tutar3 NUMBER(9):=0;
  tutar4 NUMBER(9):=0; 

BEGIN 

 FOR r IN c LOOP
    IF r.varis_tar BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
    TO_DATE('07/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN
    tutar1:=tutar1+r.tutar;
    message('tutar1',tutar1);
    
    ELSIF r.varis_tar BETWEEN TO_DATE('07/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
    TO_DATE('14/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then 
    tutar2:=tutar2+r.tutar;
    message('tutar2',tutar2);
    
    ELSIF r.varis_tar BETWEEN TO_DATE('14/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
    TO_DATE('21/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') then 
    tutar3:=tutar3+r.tutar;
    message('tutar3',tutar3);
    
    ELSIF r.varis_tar BETWEEN TO_DATE('21/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
    TO_DATE('31/10/2021', 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN
    tutar4:=tutar4+r.tutar;
    message('tutar4',tutar4);

  END IF;
 END LOOP;
```

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369337/40735-when-button-pressed-trigger-raised-unhandled-exception-ora-305500

Answer (score 0):

Your code will aggregate the rows so that the rows with identical `varis_tar` and `tutar` will be merged into a single aggregated row. Then it will loop row-by-row and perform the aggregation calling the `message` function for each cumulative step.

That is inefficient and you can `SUM` the values directly in the SQL statement using conditional aggregation and then call `message` with the final values:

```sql
declare 
  tutar1 muhasebe.doviz_takip.tutar%TYPE; 
  tutar2 muhasebe.doviz_takip.tutar%TYPE;
  tutar3 muhasebe.doviz_takip.tutar%TYPE;
  tutar4 muhasebe.doviz_takip.tutar%TYPE; 
begin 
  select SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM varis_tar) BETWEEN  1 AND  7 THEN tutar END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM varis_tar) BETWEEN  8 AND 14 THEN tutar END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM varis_tar) BETWEEN 15 AND 21 THEN tutar END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM varis_tar) BETWEEN 22 AND 31 THEN tutar END)
  into   tutar1,
         tutar2,
         tutar3,
         tutar4
  from   muhasebe.doviz_takip
  where  varis_tar >= DATE '2021-10-01'
  and    varis_tar <  DATE '2021-11-01';

  message('tutar1',tutar1);
  message('tutar2',tutar2);
  message('tutar3',tutar3);
  message('tutar4',tutar4);
end;
/
```